# Page search feature results in duplicate page for SEO

Tags: wordpress, seo, duplicates

I'm using a Wordpress theme titled Enfold which features 'Search' functionality. This functionality results in 2 URL's for every page (according to a search engine spider). The first is the actual page and the second is the link that drives the search feature.

E.g.

http://www.bhutantravelbureau.com/about-bhutan/

&

http://www.bhutantravelbureau.com/about-bhutan/?s=

To a search engine this will appear as two pages with the same content and this has a negative impact on search engine rankings.

I've attempted to fix this by using Yoast SEO to identify pages not to be found in search results, and also added

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?s=
```

to the robots.txt file.

Unfortunately this has not fixed the issue. Other than disabling the search feature, does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle it over the robots.txt because search engines ignore empty query strings.

You have a generally problem with your site, you will have every time double content, already alone because your Domain dont handle the www. and Non-www Subdomain. Use 301-Redirects and opt for only one domain (either www.domain.com or domain.com).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate domain issue, I've corrected this.
With regards to the other problem, is your suggestion that it is best to use 301-Redirect from all pages featuring the /?s= to the correct pages without it, and that nothing can be added to the robots.txt file to address this issues? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: the best solution is to handle your link printing. Remove programatically that. On your page you have set these link (<a href="?s=") no wondering if search engines index that! Remove it! or add an **noindex**

Comment: Hi Adrian. As mentioned, these a-hrefs are being added by the search functionality built into the Wordpress theme, I haven't set these links. I also tried to add a noindex using Yoast SEO as mentioned which didn't fix the problem. You mentioned 301-redirects... is this a better solution?

Comment: otherwise, edit the function or the template: Thats a better solution.